# Trying to display javascript number with commas

Tags: javascript, web

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
    height = screen.height;
    width = screen.width;
    document.write( width*height + " pixels");
</SCRIPT>
```

I would like my answer to return with commas separating the numbers rather than one full number.

Comment: Please also note that Script doesn't have a "language" attribute

Comment: Do you mean with a comma as in if width * height > 1000 you have a comma for thousand separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fun way to do it:

```
function format(num) {
    return ("" + num).split("").reverse().reduce(function(acc, num, i, orig) {
        return  num + (i && !(i % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
    }, "");
}

format(777782374);
```

Prints:

```
"777,782,374"
```

Or, if you want to support decimals:

```
function format(num, fix) {
    var p = num.toFixed(fix).split(".");
    return p[0].split("").reduceRight(function(acc, num, i, orig) {
        var pos = orig.length - i - 1
        return  num + (pos && !(pos % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
    }, "") + (p[1] ? "." + p[1] : "");
}

format(777782374, 4);
```

Prints:

```
"777,782,374.0000"
```

Comment: How can I apply that to my code? I'm still very new to javascript and I'm having trouble understanding the code.

Comment: `format(width * height)`

Comment: <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
                   height = screen.height;
                   width = screen.width;

                   function format(num, fixed) {
                      var p = num.toFixed(fixed || 1).split(".");
                         return p[0].split("").reverse().reduce(function(acc, num, i, orig) {
                         return  num + (i && !(i % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
                        }, "") + "." + p[1];
                    }

format(width * height);        
</SCRIPT>

This doesn't seem to be working. Am I still missing something?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result. You really shouldn't be using `document.write` but just to get it working, do this: `document.write(format(width * height) + " pixels");`

Comment: It still seems to be returning nothing. Here's a screenshot of the code: http://i.imgur.com/rck8WKA.jpg

Comment: You're missing a paren after `height`

Comment: Got it thanks. How would I make it display no decimal places?

Comment: I updated the answer a bit. Either use the first function (that accepts no `fix` argument) or use the second version, but do not pass an argument for `fix`.

Comment: Well done. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Than you shouldn't multiply them?

`document.write( width + ", " + height + " pixels");`

Comment: OP is showing the total number of pixels. That's why the multiplication is needed.

Comment: What he said. I'm trying to display the total amount of pixels on your screen as a whole number, but with commas. Ex: 1920 x 1080 = 2073600. But I would like for it to say 2,073,600.